# Screen capture software for streaming video

Tags: screen-recording

I need a software suggestion that would be the best option for a screen capture for a live, streaming video, like a webinar.

*QUALITY IS IMPERATIVE!* - The Higher the better.

What program should I use for this?

- It will not be needed to *edit* the video in any way, I only want to *capture*
- Price is not *really* a boundary, but it is not a defining factor.
- I do need sound and video capture, as well as the possible input I may have (using some form of microphone).

  - This should preferably capture on the same track also - I have had a bit of an issue with Bandicam at one point (free version) where the sound and video did not match up.

**EDIT:** I may have unfortunately been unclear in my request - I am actually looking to use this to record someone else's webinar. I will be watching this, and I would like to record it *as well* to review it at a later date. I am concerned about frame-drop, especially since the streaming will likely lose frames  and quality, and then *another* screen-capture program will *further* lose frames and quality.

Comment: For which operating system? Can you play the webinar also in a video player, or only on a web page?

Answer (score 4):

[Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/)

> is free and open source software for video recording and live streaming.

Hopefully the high performance

> GPU-based game capture for high performance game streaming.

allows to have a high enough quality for you. Use the [Settings estimator](https://obsproject.com/estimator)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Join.me by LogMeIn? It should be exactly what your looking for. It meets your requirements of,

- Live screen capture
- Prices range from Free to $19 per month
- Sound/microphone capture

  - Audio and screen capture should be on the same track

## [Join Me](http://join.me)

> Join.me is a quick, no registration required (for the free features)
>   remote controlling / screen & file sharing program from the makers of
>   LogMeIn. All you need to start sharing is to start the app (you don't
>   even need to install if if you don't want to) from "https://join.me/",
>   and send the code to whoever needs to see your screen. It can be
>   anywhere from one to 250 people, and all they need is to type the code
>   on the same webpage to join your meeting. Get your people together,
>   without actually getting them together. Just instantly share your
>   screen so everybody's on the same page. No need for a plane, a
>   projector or a sandwich platter. Just gather at join.me. It's join.me,
>   the last two words in an invitation to collaborate, meet, train, demo
>   or show-off.

Comment: Does this record your screen capture, or does this simply allow you to share your screen? I am looking for something to record a webinar, which I am concerned may drop in frames if I attempt to capture it using something like fraps..?

Comment: Yes, recording is an option; however, I believe it only comes with their pro subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Screen recorder studio is a great choice for streaming. It can capture sound, screen and webcam simultaneously. You can add many sources at the same time. It also supports overlaying. You can find the download link, screenshots and more information about it using the link below.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/screen-recorder-studio-screen-recorder-based-on-obs-studio/9p94835tm2lv?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Screen recorder studio is basically based on OBS Studio. Link for OBS studio - https://obsproject.com/

Comment: Welcome Ninad.  Within a period of 15 hours, you posted 6 answers recommending 2 products.  As such, your posts have been flagged by our community.  Do you have any affiliation with either product?  If so, please disclose your affiliation, in full, within each answer.  Please also add more details to each answer explaining how it fulfills the question's requirements.  Thanks, and welcome!

Answer (score -1):

[ActivePresenter](https://atomisystems.com/activepresenter/free-edition/) is a professional software application whose purpose is to help you perform video screen capture operations.
ActivePresenter gives users the possibility to select between various capturing modes. You can record the computer screen activity by pressing a key or clicking with your mouse.
What’s more, you can opt for a full screen recording mode, insert text messages, apply voice-over effects and various sounds, as well as embed transition effects. The generated project can be exported to AVI, WMV, or MP4 file format.

Comment: What is your affiliation with this product?